# Create session variable onclick hyperlink field asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net, session, variables, hyperlink, field

I am writing `asp.net` project in `C#`, my page consists of `hyperlink` field inside `gridview`. 
The code is below:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
   <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='details.aspx' Text="view details"></asp:HyperLink>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I want to handle `onclick` event on this `hyperlink` field, so that when I click on it I go to the new page and create new session variable. 
So how to create session variable and go to the new page on click of a `hyperlink`? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`LinkButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.aspx):

```
<asp:LinkButton id="LinkButton1" 
           Text="view details"              
           OnClick="LinkButton_Click" 
           runat="server"/>

void LinkButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Session["variable"] = "your_value";
    Response.Redirect("~/details.aspx");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
protected void buttonClick(Object sender, Eventargs e)
  {
   Session["variable"] = value;
   Response.Redirect("page.aspx");
   }
```

Comment: and how to call this when clicking on hyperlink field?

Comment: With a hyperlink, I think you'd set the session variable on the next page. If you want to do it before you hit the new page, use a linkbutton and attach to the click event?